# mysql binlog position and file to be identified based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I took a dump of MySQL to be imported into the slave instance and imported but I forgot to take the binlog position and file. I remember the timestamp at which the dump for the slave was taken is there any way to identify the approximate binlog file and position if so please help as this production instance and din't want to give an incorrect binlog position. I tried to check in master status and binary log events could not identify.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new dump of the source instance. This time use the `--master-data` option.

Trying to fake the binlog coordinates is not worth the risk that you'll be off a little bit, and miss some data. It will result in an untrue replica.